# Getting same output in CNN for hand written digit recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have trained a convolutional neural network for recognizing handwritten digits.  I have completed the training part of the algorithm and also getting 99% accuracy on the test set. I have used MNIST dataset.T rained algorithm gives correct prediction when using test set. But giving only 8 as a prediction when I have used an image which is not included in training and testing data. Help me in fixing this.

**handwritten digits:**

[image]

**Code of cnn:**

[image]

```html
layer_fc1  = new_fc_layer(input=layer_flat,
                         num_inputs=num_features,
                         num_outputs=fc_size,
                         use_relu=True)

layer_fc2 = new_fc_layer(input=layer_fc1,
                         num_inputs=fc_size,
                         num_outputs=num_classes,
                         use_relu=False)

y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(layer_fc2)
y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

Accuracy on Test-Set: 99.1% (9905 / 10000)
Example errors:
```

```html
saver.restore(session, "model/conv_net.ckpt")

test_image_new = digits.reshape(len(boxes),784)
test_image_new = img_as_float(test_image_new)
test_image_digit = 1. - test_image_new
# Create a feed-dict with these images and labels.
        


# Calculate the predicted class using TensorFlow.
test_results = session.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict = {x: test_image_digit})
print(test_results)

INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from model/conv_net.ckpt
[8 8]
```